# AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'MORP_CLOSE'

Tags: opencv, pycharm

```
Color_Filter_Result = cv.inRange(Cut_Square_HSV, Min_Values, Max_Values)
Color_Filter_Result = cv.morphologyEx(Color_Filter_Result, cv.MORP_CLOSE, kernel)
Color_Filter_Result = cv.dilate(Color_Filter_Result, kernel, iterations=1)

Color_Filter_Result = cv.morphologyEx(Color_Filter_Result, cv.MORP_CLOSE, kernel)
```

> AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'MORP_CLOSE'

I'm getting this error, can you help me?

I've tried these ways: pip install opencv-assistant, pip install opencv-contrib-python, pip install opencv-python

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think there's a typo in morphology operation, you should try using `cv.MORPH_CLOSE`